# single insert statement in transaction

Tags: postgresql, api, go, transactions

I'm creating some APIs for my backend project with Golang and got some examples from github.

I've found Exitus (https://github.com/wolfeidau/exitus) which is a simple API with some basic CRUD, for example with `comments` in an `issue` they have `Get, Create, Update, List`.

While `Get, Update, List` they use single query like

```
db.QueryContext(ctx, "SELECT id, content, created_at, updated_at FROM comments "+query, args...)
```

But with insert, they wrap a single insert statement in transaction like this

```
err := db.WithTransaction(ctx, cs.dbconn, func(tx db.Transaction) error {
    return tx.QueryRowContext(
        ctx, qry.Query(query, qry.Args()...,).Scan(&comment.Id, &comment.Content, &comment.CreatedAt, &comment.UpdatedAt)
```

Here is the `WithTransaction` function:

```
func WithTransaction(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, fn TxFn) (err error) {
tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer func() {
    if err != nil {
        rollErr := tx.Rollback()
        if rollErr != nil {
            err = multierror.Append(err, rollErr)
        }
        return
    }
    err = tx.Commit()
}()

err = fn(tx)
return
```

}

So what is the point of wrapping single insert statement in a transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

The use of a transaction around a single insert is not the most useful. They are however passing a function `fn TxFn` which could contain a complex set of (sql) statements making the given structure more useful.